# How to prove this function？

Tags: functions

[image]

The third question:
the left side is $f(f(x))$,and the right side is $2f(x)$
So, we need prove $f(f(x))=2f(x)$
use the $f(x)=\lfloor 2x \rfloor$
So double $\lfloor 2x \rfloor=2 \lfloor 2x \rfloor$
And I do not know how to slove it!
Thank you for answering!

Comment: Hint: If $n$ is an integer, what is $\lfloor n\rfloor$?

Answer (score 0):

$$f(x) = \lfloor 2x \rfloor \in \mathbb{Z}$$

Hence $2f(x) \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Hence $$f(f(x))=\lfloor 2f(x)\rfloor=2f(x)$$